# How to get c/c++ header system include directory in emacs lisp?

Tags: c++, c, emacs, elisp

How could I get the c/c++ header file system include directory in emacs lisp?

just like the part of output of "gcc -xc++ -E -v -"

```
/usr/include/c++/4.8
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/4.8
/usr/include/c++/4.8/backward
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/include
/usr/local/include
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/include-fixed
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/include
```

Comment: You could just use `shell-command-to-string` and parse it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CEDET has a function `semantic-gcc-get-include-paths` that returns paths for C or C++ languages...

Comment: Thank. That's exactly what I want. CEDET is too complicated for me to make it work. But the functions it provides are really useful.

Comment: @enchanter If this answer solved your problem, please consider [marking it as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). You can do so by clicking the check mark next to it.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Alex's answer, I want to mention that:

After `semantic-gcc-setup` has been called, the value of `(semantic-gcc-get-include-paths "c")` and `(semantic-gcc-get-include-paths "c++")` is stored in the buffer-local variable `semantic-dependency-system-include-path`.